# SignalR Error when renaming hub

Tags: asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub

I am encountering an issue when attempting to rename a SignalR hub.  Please note that I'm not using generated proxies with SignalR.

I have a SignalR Hub that was previously defined as:

```csharp
[HubName("WidgetHub")
public WidgetHub : Hub
{
...
}
```

Creating the proxy on the client is done using this code:

```js
this.proxy = connection.createHubProxy('WidgetHub');

this.proxy.on('WidgetUpdated', function() {
  $rootScope.$emit('refreshWidget');
});

return connection.start().then(function(connectionObj) {
  return connectionObj;
}, function(error) {
  console.log(error)
  return error.message;
});
};
```

This is working correctly, however, I now want to rename the hub.  I figured I could easily do this by specifying a new name in the [HubName()] attribute:

```csharp
[HubName("CloudHub")
public WidgetHub : Hub
{
...
}
```

And the updating the client proxy creation to reference the new hub name:

```
this.proxy = connection.createHubProxy('CloudHub');
```

However, when I do this, the client connection errors out with the following message being return:

> Error: SignalR: Connection must be started before data can be sent.
>   Call .start() before .send()

I suspected that I have a caching issue somewhere, because even after specifying the new hub name, if I reference the old hub name, it works correctly.

I have tried cleaning up IIS and all the browser caches, but to no avail.  Is there something else that I'm missing here on why changing the HubName attribute is not working for me?

Answer (score 0):

try to make your hubName as follows

```
[HubName("cloudHub")]
public WidgetHub : Hub
{
...
}
```

and create proxy like

```
this.proxy = connection.createHubProxy('cloudHub');
```

then try to start hub by calling method Start();

```
 $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
               ....
               ....
            });
```